# FireDac query returning empty result

Tags: delphi

let's straight to the point. I'm making a query with FireDac in the exact same way that I have already done. But in this time, query doesn't bring anything back. I already searched a lot about this "problem", I debbuged the code already too and everything seems right, so I need help now.

DMStockDAO:

```
function TStockDAO.GetProvidersByIdProduct(
  idProduct: integer): TList<TProvider>;
var dao : TProviderDAO;
list : TList<TProvider>;
begin
  dao := TProviderDAO.Create(Self);
  list := TList<TProvider>.Create;
  try
    with queryProvidersByIdProduct do
    begin
      ParamByName('pIdProduct').AsInteger := idProduct;
      Open;
      while not Eof do
      begin
        list.Add(dao.FindProviderById(FieldByName('IDProvider').AsInteger));
        Next;
      end;
    end;
    Result := list;
  finally
    dao.Free;
  end;
end;
```

SQL in query: "SELECT IDProvider FROM Stock WHERE IDProduct = :pIdProduct"

This code need to return a List of provider, but it gives me nothing.

DMProviderDAO:

```
function TProviderDAO.FindProviderById(id: Integer): TProvider;
var provider : TProvider;
begin
  try
    provider := TProvider.Create;
    with queryFindProviderById do
    begin
      ParamByName('pId').AsInteger := id;
      Open;
      provider.Id := FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;
      provider.ProviderName := FieldByName('ProviderName').AsString;
      provider.City := FieldByName('City').AsString;
      provider.Street := FieldByName('Street').AsString;
      provider.Number := FieldByName('Number').AsInteger;
      provider.CNPJ := FieldByName('CNPJ').AsString;
      Result := provider;
    end;
  finally
    provider.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks for the help guys!! If you need more code just say it.

Edit:
Declaration of TProviderDAO:

```
unit DMProviderDAO;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option,
  FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.Phys.Intf,
  FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.DApt, Data.DB,
  FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client, UProvider;

type
  TProviderDAO = class(TDataModule)
    queryFindProviderById: TFDQuery;
    procedure DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function FindProviderById(id : Integer) : TProvider;
  end;

var
  ProviderDAO: TProviderDAO;

implementation

uses
  DMConnection;

{%CLASSGROUP 'Vcl.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TProviderDAO.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DMConnection.TConnection.Create(Self);
end;
```

Declaration of TProvider:

```
unit UProvider;

interface

uses System.Classes;

type
  TProvider = class
    private
      FId : Integer;
      FProviderName : string;
      FCity : string;
      FStreet : string;
      FNumber : Integer;
      FCNPJ: string;
      procedure SetId(id : integer);
      procedure SetProviderName(name : string);
      procedure SetCity(city : string);
      procedure SetStreet(street : string);
      procedure SetNumber(number : Integer);
      procedure SetCNPJ(cnpj : string);
    public
      property Id: integer read FId write SetId;
      property ProviderName: string read FProviderName write SetProviderName;
      property City: string read FCity write SetCity;
      property Street: string read FStreet write SetStreet;
      property Number: Integer read FNumber write SetNumber;
      property CNPJ: string read FCNPJ write SetCNPJ;
  end;
```

Comment: Um, a) how  are TDAoProvider and TProvider defined and declared; b) what datatype is queryProvidersByIdProduct and c) why are you using this indirection of using a generic list when you ought far more easily simpy populate a local FireDAC dataset with the output of queryProvidersByIdProduct ?  Your q needs include a proper [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: a) Edited; b) TFDQuery; c) I'm relatively new to the language, so I'm repeating the things that I already know form other languages. The software it's so much complex than I showed up, but basically I need to fill some panels at the main screen, so each panel have multiple information, one of it is the providers quantity that I'm trying to reach by this code above, but it returns me nothing.

Comment: Well done.  Bear in mind that the dataset paradigm is sufficiently well supported (in breadth and depth) in Delphi that if you feel the need to step out of it to achieve a dataset-based task, you're probably going about it the wrong way.

Comment: Does it work when you _Close_ the query before changing the parameter?

Comment: @UweRaabe If I close it before open I get "I/O error 6"

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks to me that TProviderDAO.FindProviderById frees provider which references the same object as Result. As such te function always returns nil?

Comment: @Mark Nop, it doesn't even enter in while loop at TStockDAO.GetProvidersByIdProduct

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add *[SOLVED]* to the title or edit the solution into the question itself. If you've found a solution that you think might be helpful to future users of this site, post it as an answer in the space provided below for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to *Close();* the query before open it again. If you're doing the query in a loop, this is mandatory, if not, you don't necessary need to close it.

```
function TProviderDAO.FindProviderById(id: Integer): TProvider;
var provider : TProvider;
begin
  try
    provider := TProvider.Create;
    with queryFindProviderById do
    begin
      Close();
      ParamByName('pId').AsInteger := id;
      Open;
      provider.Id := FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;
      provider.ProviderName := FieldByName('ProviderName').AsString;
      provider.City := FieldByName('City').AsString;
      provider.Street := FieldByName('Street').AsString;
      provider.Number := FieldByName('Number').AsInteger;
      provider.CNPJ := FieldByName('CNPJ').AsString;
      Result := provider;
    end;
  finally
    provider.Free;
  end;
end;
```